# python pypdf to read pdf and get highlighted words

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

how to use python pypdf to read pdf and get highlighted words? I highlighted the unknown words in a pdf and I want to extract them for referencing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: not possible with pypdf and not with any PDF tool for Python I know.

Comment: Is it possible in any other programming language?

Comment: only seen support with some commercial java libs